# Rolling forecast in R with a time series

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, predictive-models

I'm currently using the `predict_rolling` function in R from the `tsDyn` package in R. I'm having some difficulty understanding how to manipulate the function to do what I want when it comes to creating a rolling forecast for a time series I have. I'm not looking for anyone to troubleshoot my code but more to get a better understanding of the characteristics of the function.

What I expect is to have a model that is trained up to 30 ($m=30$) number of observations out of a total number of 40 ($n=40$) observations in a time series. I now want to be able to predict the values of 31 to 40 using a rolling forecast where after each forecast the model is trained with the new actual value. For example, the model predicts that $pred_{31}=0.52$ but the actual is $act_{31}=0.5$ and the model now takes the $act_{31}=0.5$ and is retrained with that value along with the previous 30 values. This now occurs all the way up to the 40th observation.

My understanding is that the `fit.every=1`in the function is supposed to refit the model at every new observation. However, when I run the function without the command I still get the same MSE value $0.06762242$. So I do not understand what the difference is and whether or not the model is being updated correctly? Below is how I defined the two rolling predictions along with the model that I am using. The full code along with the data will be provided at the end.

```
test_aar<- aar(test_data1[1:30,1], m=2)
pred_roll_aar1<- predict_rolling(test_aar,newdata = test_data1[31:40,1])
pred_roll_aar2<- predict_rolling(test_aar, fit.every=1,
                                 newdata = test_data1[31:40,1])
```

Lastly, I also want to do this to create a two-day-ahead rolling forecast. In a similar situation as outlined above. And the same question comes to mind as once again I get the same MSE value $0.01180301$, regardless of using `fit.every=1` or not.

```
pred_roll_aar1_2d<- predict_rolling(test_aar, n.ahead = 2,
                                    newdata = test_data1[31:40,1])
pred_roll_aar2_2d<- predict_rolling(test_aar, n.ahead = 2,
                                    fit.every=2,
                                    newdata = test_data1[31:40,1])
```

Going along with the two-day-ahead forecast, I would expect to get an output of 9 values, but when I check the values of either two-day-ahead forecasts there are 10 values. I would suspect that on observation 30 I should get the prediction for observation 32, for observation 31 I should get the prediction for observation 33,..., all the way to observation 38 I should get the prediction for observation 40. At least that was my understanding from the documentation that stated, "unlike usual predict() methods, specifying n.ahead=2 will not generate a 1 step-ahead and a 2
step-ahead forecasts, but only enroll 2 step-ahead forecasts." (Source of the documentation for the `predict_rolling` function: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tsDyn/versions/0.9-44/topics/predict_rolling)

**SOURCE CODE**

```
test_data1<-data.frame(y=c(0.20,0.20,0.21,0.21,0.21,0.20,0.19,0.18,0.16,0.10,
                           0.02,-0.02,0.01,0.03,0.07,0.14,0.22,0.13,0.12,
                           0.16,0.17,0.18,0.18,0.17,0.15,0.15,0.13,0.12,
                           0.10,0.08,0.06,0.04,0.03,0.02,0.03,0.05,0.34,
                           0.13,0.11,0.12))
require("tsDyn")
require("forecast")
test_aar<- aar(test_data1[1:30,1], m=2)
#1 Day ahead

pred_roll_aar1<- predict_rolling(test_aar,newdata = test_data1[31:40,1])
pred_roll_aar1_mse<- accuracy(unlist(pred_roll_aar1$pred), 
                      unlist(pred_roll_aar1$true))[1,2]^2
pred_roll_aar1_mse
pred_roll_aar2<- predict_rolling(test_aar, fit.every=1,
                                 newdata = test_data1[31:40,1])
pred_roll_aar2_mse<- accuracy(unlist(pred_roll_aar2$pred), 
                          unlist(pred_roll_aar2$true))[1,2]^2
pred_roll_aar2_mse

# Two day ahead
pred_roll_aar1_2d<- predict_rolling(test_aar, n.ahead = 2,
                                    newdata = test_data1[31:40,1])
pred_roll_aar1_mse_2d<- accuracy(unlist(pred_roll_aar1_2d$pred), 
                          unlist(pred_roll_aar1_2d$true))[1,2]^2
pred_roll_aar1_mse_2d

pred_roll_aar2_2d<- predict_rolling(test_aar, n.ahead = 2,
                                    fit.every=2,
                                    newdata = test_data1[31:40,1])
pred_roll_aar2_mse_2d<- accuracy(unlist(pred_roll_aar2_2d$pred), 
                             unlist(pred_roll_aar2_2d$true))[1,2]^2
pred_roll_aar2_mse_2d
```